# Enable Provisioned Concurrency for a Lambda Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using Terraform, I have a confiuration for an AWS HTTP API Gateway like so:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer" "authorizer" {
  api_id = module.api_gateway.this_apigatewayv2_api_id
  name   = "authorizer"
  authorizer_payload_format_version = "2.0"
  enable_simple_responses           = true
  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds  = var.authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds
  authorizer_type  = "REQUEST"
  identity_sources = ["$request.header.Authorization"]
 
  # Problem is below:
  authorizer_uri = module.auth-authorizer-lambda.this_lambda_function_invoke_arn
}
```

when I use `this_lambda_function_invoke_arn`, this works fine but a Concurrency-provisioned version of the Lambda is not called (so the Lambda can work for, like, 4s). Typically one can refer to such a version by `this_lambda_function_qualified_arn`, but using it would result in an error:

```
Error: error updating API Gateway v2 authorizer: BadRequestException: Invalid Authorizer URI:
arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:<account-id>:function:authorizer:5. 
Authorizer URI should be a valid API Gateway ARN that represents a Lambda function invocation.
```

How can I configure API gateway to use the particular version of an Authorizer lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not shown what `auth-authorizer-lambda` module is, but the use of `this_lambda_function_invoke_arn` is incorrect. The correct form of `authorizer_uri` is shown in the [following example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-authorizer.html#cfn-apigatewayv2-authorizer-authorizeruri):

```
arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:{account_id}:function:{lambda_function_name}/invocations
```

So you have to construct and provide the `authorizer_uri` in the form as shown above. Obviously, it must be adjusted with your region, account id and function name.

Comment: This does not explain how to reference a particular alias or version of a function. You can only set provisioned concurrency on a alias or version, but it seems for apigw custom authorizers you can only specify a generic invocation uri?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this... you can configure API gateway to use the particular version of an Authorizer lambda by using the invoke_arn of the alias.

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "test_lambda_alias" {
  name             = "my_alias"
  description      = "a sample description"
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function_test.arn
  function_version = "1"
}
```

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer" "authorizer" {
  api_id = module.api_gateway.this_apigatewayv2_api_id
  name   = "authorizer"
  authorizer_payload_format_version = "2.0"
  enable_simple_responses           = true
  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds  = var.authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds
  authorizer_type  = "REQUEST"
  identity_sources = ["$request.header.Authorization"]
 
  # Problem is below:
  authorizer_uri = aws_lambda_alias.test_lambda_alias.invoke_arn
}
```

Then, as always don't forget to deploy the change to a stage to take effect.

The final reference will be this format:
`arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:{account_id}:function:{lambda_function_name}:{lambda_alias}/invocations`